# Is it possible to speed up debootstrap by disabling fsync()?

Tags: debian, fsync

I think I was able to speed up creating a Fedora chroot (`dnf --installroot=...`) using `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/nosync/nosync.so`.  But that doesn't seem to help for `debootstrap`.  I think it still uses `fsync()`, just looking at the performance / disk activity (particularly the "Unpacking" lines).  Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason LD_PRELOAD doesn't work for debootstrap is probably due to using `chroot`.

Officially, it looks like this isn't supported at the moment: [#700633 - Debootstrap is very slow. Please use eatmydata to fix this](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=700633).  Note the time difference should only be significant if you're forced to work on an old-style spinning disk.  There may also be other possible workarounds.  LXC caches a minimal debian install.  Once you have a minimal install, you can use the Debian `eatmydata` package to bypass fsync for subsequent package installs.

However if you really need this, it *is* possible to get an LD_PRELOAD library into the chroot.  I was surprised to see the Fedora `nosync.so` worked in a Debian chroot (i.e. with a foreign, older libc) - I wouldn't consider this a reliable combination.

debootstrap mounts `/proc` as you would expect, which makes it easy to escape the chroot.

### with Fedora nosync

```
sudo sh -c '
exec 3< /usr/lib64/nosync/nosync.so
LD_PRELOAD=/proc/$$/fd/3 time debootstrap --arch=amd64 --variant=minbase jessie jessie-tree http://ftp.debian.org/debian
'
```

### with Debian eatmydata

```
sudo sh -c '
exec 3< /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libeatmydata.so
LD_PRELOAD=/proc/$$/fd/3 time debootstrap --arch=amd64 --variant=minbase jessie jessie-tree http://ftp.debian.org/debian
'
```

### Results

It saved less than 20 seconds on a SATA SSD, which otherwise took 100 seconds).  The main limiting factor in this case appeared to be the CPU (a mobile i5 from 2010).

On a laptop with a hard drive (and an i5 CPU from 2015) it saved 80 seconds, from a starting point of 135 seconds.  The same technique is needed/applicable for `mkosi`.  Building a systemd test image, it appeared to save 8 minutes, out of 14.